# How to audit with quarkus, hibernate envers and keycloak

Tags: vue.js, keycloak, quarkus, hibernate-envers

I need to audit every action of the users, that are logged on my Keycloak server. I'm using Quarkus with Hibernate envers on the back side, and vue.js on the frontside. Is there a way that I can make this communication, vue / keycloak / quarkus, without having to send the user logged in every request that I make?

Comment: Can you please explain: "send the user logged in every request"

Comment: I'm sending the username in my requests(POST, DELETE, UPDATE) in the frontend, so the back can know who is doing the actions

Comment: @kinzkowski using jwt token in request header is recommended. Keycloak provides the token. vue.js to embed the header in request to quarkus. And on quarkus, it should intercept the header and do all the logging (I am assuming into db table). More work, but this is pretty standard way of doing it.